# Error connecting to MySQL: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR:

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, crud

[the i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzi99.png)

I created an update feature with the http get method, but the feature doesn't work. when i run the feature it just executes the res.redirect() function without changing the changes i made

```
router.post('/edit', (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.body.id;
  const nama = req.body.nama;
  const nohp = req.body.nohp;
  const email = req.body.email;

  // Menggunakan parameterized query untuk mencegah SQL Injection
  let sql = 'update `user` SET nama=?, nohp=?, email=? WHERE id=?';

  let query = conn.query(sql, [nama, nohp, email, userId], (err, result, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error connecting to MySQL: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

The root of the problem is in the post method. I have tried changing the SQL variable several times but to no avail. I have also asked using chat-gpt but to no avail

Comment: The title `error connecting to MySQL` is misleading. The problem here is simply MySQL can't identify some columns you are trying to update. Just double-check the column name, and case sensitivity. Probably enable logging to see the generated query.